# Android, setting time between alerts

Tags: android

Hi I am trying to escalate alerts if a user has exited a Geofence boundary and I am confused on how to implement it, I would appreciate any help as its quite a late change and would like to get it implemented quite quickly.

Order of Events:

A user can specify the time between alerts in settings (Default 2 mins).

If they are outside the Geofence - alert dialog appears.

If they are still outside in 2 mins from the alert dialog, use speech alerts

If they are still outside in 2 mins from the speech alerts, use speech and vibrate

If they are still outside in 2 mins from the speech and vibrate, send sms.

Can anyone help me get started please?

This is what I have so far.

```
        // Getting the time value the user has saved in settings
        String alertTime = SP.getString("alert_time", "2");
        int  escalateTime = Integer.parseInt(alertTime);
        int timeSeconds = alertTime * 60;

         if (distance[0] > mCircle.getRadius()) {
                    timeNow = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;

}
```

After this I am not sure on how to do the timing correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Handler` to run code delayed, here is something you can start with:

```
private Handler handler;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
    handler=new Handler();
    ...
}

public void locationUpdated() { //call this every time GPS changes
    if (isOutside()) {
        if (!dialog shown) {
            showAlertDialog();
        }
    } else {
        if (handler.hasMessages(0)) {
            handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null); //not outside, remove all delayed code
        }
        //TODO remove alertdialog if shown
    }
}

private void showAlertDialog() {
    //TODO show alertDialog here
    handler.postDelayed(new SpeechAlert(), 2*1000*60);
}

class SpeechAlert implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        //TODO do speech alert here ...
        handler.postDelayed(new SpeechAndVibrateAlert(), 2*1000*60);
    }
}

class SpeechAndVibrateAlert implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        //TODO do speech and vibrate alert ...
        handler.postDelayed(..., 2*1000*60);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, The alert dialog allows the user to click ok and still interact with the application, would this be possible in this code?